# how to store value of 2 inputs dynamically generated in state at once

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am using react.i have 2 inputs that by clicking a button dynamically ganerats.
this the code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
        const myFields = fieldsArray.map((field) => {
            return (
                <div key={field} className="col-12 m-auto d-flex">
                    <input id={field} name={`question${field}`} onChange={handleChangeFields} placeholder='سوال' className="form-control col-4 m-2" />
                    <input id={field} name={`answer${field}`} onChange={handleChangeFields} placeholder='جواب' className="form-control col-4 m-2" />
                </div>
            )
        })
        setFields(myFields)
    }, [fieldsArray])
```

i need to save value of 2 inputs together in an opjects like this :

```
[{question : '',answer : ''}]
```

and the new 2 input's value are going to update the above array like this:

```
[{question : '',answer : ''}, {question : '',answer : ''}]
```

i can save each input's value separately like this :

```
  const handleChangeFields = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target
        setFieldsValue([...fieldsValue, { [name]: value }])
    }
```

but i want each 2 input's value together
i need to save each 2 inputs together.
how do i do that?

Comment: You can not. because you will have a trigger on change event two times.

Comment: how can i do this senario?

Comment: Instead of attaching the handlers to the inputs you could have a button that has an `onClick` listener, so the state only gets updated once with those input values when it is clicked, but Ajay is right, what you're asking for with your current configuration is not possible.

Comment: how does it possible with an onClick get the value of inputs?

Comment: what configuration  do you suggest andy? :(

Comment: Bear with me. I'm writing an example. Basically I think you need a mixture of both a) keeping the input changes in state (`form`) when they're updated, and b) updating the array (`data`) when the button is clicked? Does that sound like a reasonable compromise?

Comment: yes that's right. thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem solved for me :

```
function App() {
  const [results, setResults] = useState([{ question: "", answer: "" }])

  // handle input change
  const handleInputChange = (e, index) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target
    const list = [...results]
    list[index][name] = value
    setResults(list)
  }

  // handle click event of the Remove button
  const handleRemoveClick = (index) => {
    const list = [...results]
    list.splice(index, 1)
    setResults(list)
  }

  // handle click event of the Add button
  const handleAddClick = () => {
    setResults([...results, { question: "", answer: "" }])
  }

  // handle submit to servers
  const handlesubmit = () => {
    // axios
    console.log(results)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {results?.map((result, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            <input
              name="question"
              value={result.question}
              onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, index)}
            />
            <input
              name="answer"
              value={result.answer}
              onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, index)}
            />
            {results.length !== 1 && (
              <button onClick={() => handleRemoveClick(index)}>
                Remove
              </button>
            )}
            {results.length - 1 === index && (
              <button onClick={handleAddClick}>add</button>
            )}
          </div>
        )
      })}
      <div style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>{JSON.stringify(results)}</div>
      <button onClick={handlesubmit}>submit</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

This is a general example of how I think you can tie in what you're currently doing, and add in as little new code as possible. This logs the new `data` state when the button is clicked.

1. Have two states. One for collecting the updated form information (`form`), and another for the combined form data array (`data`).
2. Have a form with a single `onChange` listener ([event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/)) so you can catch events from all the inputs as they bubble up the DOM. That listener calls the `handleChange` function which updates the form state.
3. Have a button with an `onClick` listener that calls `handleClick` which takes the current form state and adds it to the `data` state.
4. I would be a bit wary of storing JSX in state. You should have that `map` in the component `return` and only updating the actual field data with basic information.
5. One final issue - your inputs cannot have the same `id`. `ids` must be unique. I'd get rid of them altogether.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

function Example() {

  // Initialise two states. `data` is an array
  // and `form` is an object
  const [ data, setData ] = useState([]);
  const [ form, setForm ] = useState({});

  // Add the form data to the `data` array
  function handleClick() {
    setData([ ...data, form ]);
  }

  // We're using event delegation so we need to
  // check what element we changed/clicked on
  // - in this case the INPUT element. We can then
  // update the form state with the name/value pair of that input
  function handleChange(e) {
    const { nodeName, name, value } = e.target;
    if (nodeName === 'INPUT') {
      setForm({ ...form, [name]: value });
    }
  }

  // Just logs the data state after a change
  useEffect(() => console.log(data), [data]);

  return (
    <form onChange={handleChange}>
      <input name="question" type="text" />
      <input name="answer" type="text" />
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={handleClick}
      >Update form
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: this is right thank you but in my code the inputs generate dynamically by clicking the button.
by clicking the button there is 2 more inputs.
and user can edit the previous inputs

Comment: Without really understanding what `fieldsArray` is or how the user updates it I can't really go any further.

Comment: it is an array that i made that my every click on button, one item pushes in to it and rerenders the page and now we have new pare of inputs.

Comment: something like this :
[link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66469913/how-to-add-input-field-dynamically-when-user-click-on-button-in-react-js)